# Postgresql current_query without casting operator

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

Is there any way to remove the ::numeric(10) or ::text from the result of current_query inside a trigger function of postgresql?

Now I am getting :

```
DELETE FROM department WHERE department_id = '1000007'::numeric(10,0)
```

but I need it to be

```
DELETE FROM department WHERE department_id = '1000007'
```

I just want to log this statement to another table.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If `department_id` is a numeric column, you should use `WHERE department_id = 1000007`. `'1000007'` is a character literal, `1000007` is a number.

Comment: I need it without the type casting, the single quote is fine for me. I tried replacing those with replace function but would like to know is there any standard ways to do it. I am logging this statement from a trigger.

Comment: If you get rid of the quotes, you don't need the cast.

Comment: I need to remove ::numeric(10,0) only

Comment: No. You need to use a proper integer literal. As long as you don't use that you will need a cast. If you get rid of the useless single quotes you don't need the cast in the first place. Don't compare apples (strings) with oranges (numbers).